# How to Implement linq on dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, dictionary, razor

I am facing a problem while creating online exam portal using linq on dictionary in C#. My concern is to get Online Exam category, SubCategory. I made a request to database server to fetch my data. Now my data is available at front end but I am trying to fetch record in a convenient way so that I can divide my data in Category, Subcategory and questions. for example I want my Headline and category to be like:-

**General Knowledge**

- Basic General Knowledge
- World Geography
- Inventions
- Honours and Awards

**Maths**

- Time & Speed
- Algebra
- Accounts

but with below given code my result is being displayed

**General Knowledge**

- Basic General Knowledge
- Basic General Knowledge
- Basic General Knowledge

this is getting repeated according to the number of question per subcategory.

Code I am using is

```
 public ActionResult getOnlineTestTitle()
    {
        List<GopreadyOnlineTest> search;
        if (Session["OnlineTest"] == null)
        {
             search= GopreadyOnlineTest.Search(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["liveData"].ConnectionString).ToList();
             Session["OnlineTest"] = search;
        }
        else
        {
            search = (List<GopreadyOnlineTest>)Session["OnlineTest"];
        }            
        List<string> categoryName = search.Select(x => x.CategoryName).Distinct().ToList();
        Dictionary<string, List<GopreadyOnlineTest>> result2 = new Dictionary<string, List<GopreadyOnlineTest>>();
        foreach (string item in categoryName)
        {
            result2.Add(item, search.Where(s => s.CategoryName.ToUpper() == item.ToUpper()).ToList());
        }
        return Json(result2, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
    }
```

Here is my proc which is returning me the data.

```
alter proc Quiz_SEARCH
(
    @CategoryName varchar(200) = null,
    @SubCategoryName varchar(200) = null
)
as
select c.catId as 'CategoryId', c.catName as 'CategoryName', s.subCatId as 'SubCategoryId', s.subCatName as 'SubCategoryName',
 q.question as 'Question', q.opta as 'OptionA',
q.optb as 'OptionB', q.optc as 'OptionC', q.optd as 'OptionD', q.answer, q.quesDescription as 'QuestionDescription'
from quizcategory c join quizsubcategory s on c.catid=s.catid
join quizquestion q on s.subcatid = q.subcatid
where 
(@CategoryName is null or [CatName]=@CategoryName)
and
(@subcategoryName is null or [SubCatName]=@SubCategoryName)

     ----------
```

Please help by solving this. If I put following line to solve the problem it is not allowing me to do this.

```
result2.Add(item, search.Where(s => s.CategoryName.ToUpper() == item.ToUpper()).Select(x=>x.SubCategoryName).Distinct().ToList());
```

Here is my jquery which is designing the page dynamically.

```
function GetOnlineTestTitle() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getOnlineTestTitle",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) { 
            var htmlString = '';
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
            $("#examList").html(htmlString);
            $.each(msg, function (key, val) {
                if (val.length != 0) {
                    htmlString += '<li><h3>' + key + '</h3></li>';
                }
                $.each(val, function (key2, val2) {
                    htmlString += '<li><a href="#"><b>'+val2.SubCategoryName+'</b></a></li>';
                });
            });
            $('#examList').append(htmlString);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Error:" + JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I gess you should use `GroupBy`

Comment: I tried that too. But didn't work out.:-)

Comment: could you post  your View which show the category?

Comment: i also face the same problem.

Comment: @kcwu I am using ajax call to design the layout.

Comment: have you tried   
`var result = search.GroupBy(p => p.CategoryName);` guess result will be   `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, GopreadyOnlineTest>> `, and the key of IGrouping is `CategoryName`. then just `return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use GroupBy method from LINQ to do that, see below.

Assuming that your **GopreadyOnlineTest** class is like that:

```
public class GopreadyOnlineTest
{
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryId { get; set; }
    public string SubCategoryName { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public string OptionA { get; set; }
    public string OptionB { get; set; }
    public string OptionC { get; set; }
    public string OptionD { get; set; }
    public string QuestionDescription { get; set; }
}
```

And your `List<GopreadyOnlineTest> search` variable contains some data like that:

```
this.search = new List<GopreadyOnlineTest> 
{
    new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "General Knowledge", SubCategoryName = "Basic General Knowledge" },
    new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "General Knowledge", SubCategoryName = "World Geography" },
    new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "General Knowledge", SubCategoryName = "Inventions" },
    new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "General Knowledge", SubCategoryName = "Honours and Awards" },
    new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "Maths", SubCategoryName = "Time & Speed" },
    new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "Maths", SubCategoryName = "Algebra" },
    new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "Maths", SubCategoryName = "Accounts" }
};
```

Lets create a ViewModel to hold our transformed data

```
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public List<string> SubCategories { get; set; }
}
```

Then your action should be like that:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetOnlineTestTitle()
{               
    var result = search.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryName)
                       .Select(c => new SampleViewModel 
                                    { 
                                        Category = c.Key, 
                                        SubCategories = c.Select(sc => sc.SubCategoryName).Distinct().ToList() 
                                    });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in front end, your javascript should be like that:

```
function GetOnlineTestTitle() {    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'GetOnlineTestTitle',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) { 
            $("#examList").html("");
            var divs = msg.map(function (item) {
                var $div = $("<div>"); 
                var $ul = $("<ul>"); 
                var $h3 = $("<h3>").text(item.Category);

                item.SubCategories.forEach(function (itemSub) {
                    $ul.append($("<li>").text(itemSub));
                });
                $div.append($h3);
                $div.append($ul);
                return $div;
            });
            $('#examList').append(divs);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
    });
}
```

You can see it working here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PdaW67

Since the code above is more didatic, I am adding below almost real code for your case:

```
public ActionResult getOnlineTestTitle()
{
    var connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["liveData"].ConnectionString;
    List<GopreadyOnlineTest> search = Session["OnlineTest"] as List<GopreadyOnlineTest> 
                                      ?? GopreadyOnlineTest.Search(connectionString).ToList();

    Session["OnlineTest"] = search;

    var result = search.GroupBy(x => x.CategoryName)
                       .Select(c => new SampleViewModel 
                                    { 
                                        Category = c.Key, 
                                        SubCategories = c.Select(sc => sc.SubCategoryName).Distinct().ToList() 
                                    });
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);            
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alberto Moteiro. You saved a lot of time of mine.

Comment: @RaviKantHudda I am glad that I could help you!!

Comment: I am still facing the same problem. Actually I have to fetch data from database. So say basic general knowledge is having 4 records so this is repeating 4 times.                new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "General Knowledge", SubCategoryName = "Basic General Knowledge" },
                new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "General Knowledge", SubCategoryName = "Basic General Knowledge" },
                new GopreadyOnlineTest { CategoryName = "General Knowledge", SubCategoryName = "Basic General Knowledge" },

Comment: @RaviKantHudda Is the data comming from your database right?

Comment: Yes it is coming from database. But if you can resolve above given problem than it would be so nice to you. Say i have basic general knowledge repeated 3 times then how would your solution solve the problem.

Comment: @RaviKantHudda I guess that your query is returning the wrong Data, that is repeating 3 times. I mean, the data return from `GopreadyOnlineTest.Search` method, is already repeated. Can you provide the data returned from this method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99237/discussion-between-ravikant-hudda-and-alberto-monteiro).

Comment: What if beside declaring constructor for defining the list variable. I tried it in ActionResult but it is giving me null value. Actually my controller contains multiple actions so I want this to be defined in OnlineTest Action but in jsonresult function it says list is null.

Comment: @RaviKantHudda I made it in constructor just from didatic purpose, you must use things in your Action. I am going to add the "almost" real code in my answer

Comment: @RaviKantHudda I did it